# Help for rendering with Azure Batch

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to set up blender to render files with Azure Batch.
The only addons found are not working (like azure-batch-apps-blender
probably too old - 2015 and no more updated).

Do you have any advise for this kind of setup?

Thank you.